# Having problems adding another element to the plot such as (fill between, scatterplot) to the line plot already exists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

[image: This is how the plot should look like(don't mind the label etc)][image]Getting a: **ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1**
while adding another element to the plot such as fill between or scatterplot to the line plot already exists.

If I remove the line plot, it lets me run the scatterplot/fill between.

## This is the output of df.head(20):

```
             Date Element  Data_Value
18049  2005-01-01    TMAX          56
35479  2005-01-01    TMIN         -39
49823  2005-01-01    TMAX         150
17153  2005-01-01    TMAX         150
49827  2005-01-01    TMIN         -39
31718  2005-01-01    TMIN         -44
55424  2005-01-01    TMAX         150
35771  2005-01-01    TMAX         122
35785  2005-01-01    TMIN         -39
31715  2005-01-01    TMAX         156
39569  2005-01-01    TMAX         144
39565  2005-01-01    TMIN         -22
3058   2005-01-01    TMAX         128
19772  2005-01-01    TMAX         128
19769  2005-01-01    TMIN         -33
55102  2005-01-01    TMAX          67
1906   2005-01-01    TMIN         -17
55067  2005-01-01    TMIN         -28
39468  2005-01-01    TMIN         -28
39454  2005-01-01    TMAX          28
```

## This is the code:

```
df = 
pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index()

df15 = df[df.index.year == 2015]
df15 = df15.reset_index()

df = df[~(df.index.year == 2015)]
df = df[~((df.index.month == 2) & (df.index.day == 29))]
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(by = ['Date', 'Data_Value'], ascending = [1, 0])

maxlst = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].max().sort_index()
minlst = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].min().sort_index()

maxlst15 = df15.groupby(df15['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].max().sort_index()
minlst15 = df15.groupby(df15['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].min().sort_index()

max_record15 = np.where(maxlst15.values > maxlst.values)[0]
min_record15 = np.where(minlst15.values < minlst.values)[0]

date_lst = []
for dt in list(maxlst.sort_index().index):
    date_lst.append(datetime.strptime(dt, "%m-%d"))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(date_lst, maxlst, '-', date_lst, minlst, '-')
#when adding this row i get the error:
plt.scatter(max_record15, maxlst15.iloc[max_record15], s=10, color='red', label='High temp record broken (2015)')
plt.scatter(min_record15, maxlst15.iloc[min_record15], s=10, color='green', label='Low temp record broken (2015)')
#this line gives my the same error:
#plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(minlst)), minlst, maxlst, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.25)
plt.show()
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

with a bunch of trace calls.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As we can't see your csv or data, please read up on posting a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you share the contents of `max_record15 ` and a sample of `maxlst15`?

Comment: This is maxlst:
Date
01-01    156
01-02    139
01-03    133
01-04    106
01-05    128
01-06    189
01-07    217
01-08    194
01-09    178
01-10    100
01-11    156

Comment: That's max_record15:
[ 39 106 126 127 130 137 207 209 230 249 250 258 259 260 270 271 292 305
 306 307 308 309 321 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 356 357 358
 359]

Comment: @Eyal Try posting a sample of your `df`, such as `df.head()`, by editing your question and formatting it correctly. This will give us a better idea of what way your data looks like.

Comment: @Tom thanks, I uploaded a df.head() shot

Comment: Screenshots aren't that helpful, so please copy the data here.  [Provide a copy of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Comment: Data copied, Thanks

Comment: You are trying to plot dates in the same axes as some other numbers. How do you imagine this to work or look like? (In the sense of should the 1 of April appear left or right of the number 42?)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a pic of how the plot should look like eventually(don't mind the label etc)